# Check Treeview Nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I use a `treeview` of `checkboxes`.
The root nodes specify the group name.

When the user check the root node I would like to check all its nested notes.

Therefore, I would like to use the `CheckChanged` event of CheckBox in the treeview.

Is  it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AfterCheck event and another help procedure, called recursively. Something like this:

```
    private void tvwTest_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        checkNodes(e.Node);
    }

    private void checkNodes(TreeNode root)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in root.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = root.Checked;
            checkNodes(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! As a new with winForms, how can I add the `tvwTest_AfterCheck` event?

Comment: In design on the properties window of tree view click on events button (with small lightning) and double click on AfterClick row.